# таблица для mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица со списком доменов: `domains` где есть поля *id* и *name*

И есть информация для всех доменов: `info` где есть *id domainid name*

Так вот: получается привязка информации к домену идет через domainid. Но у всех ячеек info свои отдельные id
Эффективна ли такая cтруктура?  И в случае 3-его уровня таблицы зависимой от info, им тоже отдельные id выставлять?

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под фразой "Но у всех блоков info"?

Comment: Приведите примеры записей в перечисленных таблицах, чтобы вопрос был более понятен, и чтобы можно было говорить об эффективности выбранной структуры.

Comment: @zverkov, дописал, почему то обрезалось. записи любые могут быть со значениями, и с любым количеством. Хотел узнать не будет ли проблем с временем запроса к какой то записи если их будет 1000000 к примеру

Comment: Почему не добавите поле info в таблицу domains, и не запишите информацию в одну таблицу?

Comment: Если эти таблицы в отношении один к одному, то **возможно** стоит их объединить. Мы не знаем всей картины. А без знания контекста нельзя рассуждать насколько оно эффективно.

Answer (score 1):

Это называется "нормализация" и это обычная практика в реляционных базах данных.
Да, в случае 3-го и так далее уровня отношений будет аналогичная ситуация.
Да, это влечёт некоторые расходы. Поэтому *в исключительных случаях*, в критичных ко времени местах, разработчики допускают де-нормализацию: производительность в обмен на избыточность.

Читать:

- [Нормализация](https://habrahabr.ru/post/129195/)
- [Денормализация](http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/1095/191/lecture/4985?page=3)